# Show Surjective Homomorphism but Not Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ and $H$ are two groups, how do I show that the map $\phi:G\times H\to G$ such that $\phi((g,h))=g$ is a surjective homomorphism but not an isomorphism?

Comment: It's because for every $g$ there exists a couple $(g,h)$ but that couple is not unique.

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt Thank you. But, is there a way to formally write this?

Comment: $\forall g\in G \exists (g,h)\in G\times H$ but nothing tells us that $\nexists h'\in H-\{h\}$ s.t. $\phi ((g,h')) = g$.

Basically H can have more than just one element...

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt Ah I see. Thanks! One more related question. If $\phi(g)=(g,e_H)$, $e_H$ is the identity in $H$, then is it true that this is now an injective homomorphism and not an isomorphism?

Comment: I guess it is bijective yes

Comment: @StanislasHildebrandt I'm still not seeing how it shows that it isn't an isomorphism. Can you expand on this a ltitle bit?

Comment: What about the function $f:G\longrightarrow G\times \{"hellomynameisstanislas"\}$ defined by $f(g)=(g,"hellomynameisstanislas")$ ? What is a surjection/injection/bijection?

Comment: If $H$ is the trivial group, this map is a isomorphism!

Answer (score 2):

An isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism.

Now, $\ker \phi = \{ (1,h) : h \in H \}$ and so $\phi$ is injective iff $H=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $|H|\geq2$ then $\exists h'\not=h \in H$ such that $\phi((g,h))=\phi((g,h'))=g$ but $(g,h)\not=(g,h')$